# is there a function to update database based on time

Tags: flutter, sqflite

i'm working on an app that help doctors calculate the volume and dosage of drug and save the rest in the database(if there is a rest) and this drug have an expiration date so i want to delete the drug automatically after expiration ,i want help how to implement the function

```
DatabaseHelper  databaseHelper=DatabaseHelper();
List<Medecine> medecineList2 = await databaseHelper.getMedecineList();
int count=medecineList2.length;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  DateTime tempDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
      .parse(medecineList2[i].date_reliquat);
  DateTime x = tempDate.add(Duration(minutes: medecineList2[i].stabilitie));
  if(now.isAfter(x) ){


    medecineList2[i].reliquat=0;
    medecineList2[i].date_reliquat='';

    await databaseHelper.updateMedecine(medecineList2[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you don't need delete rows, you can only "not select" them, for that put a where in select filtering by expiration date. With this you can keep a history

Comment: i think this test   if(now.isAfter(x) ) do not work ,it's like the two dates are not comparing